# How to make Tabs to take full width? [com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout]

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

There are other questions about it but all of them answers how to take full witdh in **XML tag**:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

and the answer (**above**) didn't work in my project's **XML tag**:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout/>
```

I am using **`ConstraintLayout`** as a root:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

It should be possible but it seems that I can't find an answer. 
So how to fill root width with fixed number of `Tabs`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was so simple. The key is use:
**`android:layout_width="0dp"`** instead of **`app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"`**, 
 with **`app:tabGravity`** and **`app:tabMode`**

Here is full tag:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```